# Can I resuse the same onload.js function for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, onload

We are migrating our project from Ang JS to React JS and we already have onload.js file which is written Jquery. Can I use the same onload file in ReactJS too. This file has user privilege information.

Before starting to work on it, I would like to know whether i need to start rewriting the code in newer syntax without jquery or should I use the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use jQuery in React. React itself is already manipulating the DOM, and throwing jQuery on that will confuse it, possibly causing unwanted effects.

So yes, you need to rewrite your code. You probably don't want to be sending sensitive information to the client's browser anyways though?